# Keychain SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain

I'm having issues with accessing Keychain on a device. This happens only when the app is launched from Xcode. If I launch the app by myself (by tapping on its icon) the Keychain works without any problems. No issues in simulator either.

Console output:

```
Jan 27 14:33:24 iPhone MyApp[4305] <Error>:  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
Jan 27 14:33:24 iPhone securityd[77] <Error>:  securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler MyApp[4305] delete The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements)
```

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.1.

It's worth noting that the app I'm trying to debug has the code for accessing keychain as located in a **Cocoa Touch framework** target (This could be the source of the problem).

The provisioning profile is a generic one: `iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *` (Managed by Xcode)

Comment: Do you have any entitlement file added to Project?

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR Nope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSStatus error code -34018](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740952/osstatus-error-code-34018)

Answer (score 2):

Try **disabling all breakpoints when launching the app** from Xcode.
You can enable them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There are **2 ways you can resolve this issue**.

1. Add entitlement file to your project.
   [image]
2. Forcefully add folder code signing to your target through code signing.

> codesign --verify --force --sign
>   "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY""$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"

[image]

Comment: I still have the problem happening. It only happens when my app is re-opened via a Deeplink with the following app delegate method: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url If I just start the app, keychain writing works, and if I minimize and maximize the app, it still works. It's only when I re-open with the deep link that this problem occurs. I do have MyApp.entitlements configured in my project ( Keychain Sharing in the Capabilities tab)

Answer (score 0):

In the Build Phases of your Target add a Run Script containing:

```
codesign --verify --force --sign "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"
```

Example:
[image: adding a Run Script]

I'm not sure why this should be required, but it worked for me to overcome a very similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8 bug may also lead this.

Github issue: [KeychainAccess issue](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess/issues/52)