# Error -34018 when saving to keychain only on one of my devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, keychain

I am saving an login hash to the users keychain, however it seems it doesn't always work.

I have tested different libraries, the last one I use is [Keychain-Swift](https://github.com/exchangegroup/keychain-swift).
I got it working on an iPhone 6+ with iOS 8.4.1 and an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.0.2. However, an other iPhone 6+ also with iOS 9.0.2 returns error `-34018` on `SecItemAdd`.

The only difference between the devices is that the device which doesn't work is my personal device and the other devices are my test devices.

I have check the code signing and that is correct. Added an entitlement as well with the `Keychain Access Groups`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't already [an answer](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&q=34018) to this question ?

Comment: There is an answer, I just don't know it. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked for it.

Comment: In case you haven't tried, I would start by clearing the DerivedData folder, removing all profiles from your phone (in Settings->General->Profiles), refreshing all provisioning profiles from Xcode accounts preferences and [clearing the keychain](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9358a6caec9ea0e2be8) of your phone of possible stale data.

Comment: Haven't tried the removing of profiles on the device nor clearing of the device keychain, but the derived data, restart, restart of phone, reset of provisioning profiles, re-adding of accounts in xcode I have tried. Thanks, I'll give it a go.

Comment: In my experience you experience problems with keychain and push notifications when your bundle id doesn't match that of the provisioning profile. But it will still compile and sign because Xcode will automatically chose a wildcard provisioning profile. Can you create an app store build of your app and validate it ?

Comment: I sign my app with the adhoc provision and release successfully to Fabric. Push works as well. I don't think it's that, however I have consisted and tried it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93775/discussion-between-paul-peelen-and-deadbeef).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSStatus error code -34018](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740952/osstatus-error-code-34018)